# Two counts with different status in one group in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, status

> *SELECT services, COUNT( * ) AS Total_queue, COUNT( * ) AS balance_queue
>   FROM tqueue
>   WHERE STATUS IN ('8','4') and STATUS ('4')
>   AND get_tiket
>   BETWEEN  '2016-11-10 00:00:01'
>   AND  '2016-11-10 23:59:59'
>   GROUP BY services*

but not working, if just 1 status is working

I want to have 2 result Total_queue with 2 number status (8 and 4) but balance_queue with just one status (4),

```
DATA TABLE
-----------------------------------
  Total_queue  |   balance_queue   
.-------------------------------------
      ___  7    __   |  ___5_____         
-
```

Amount 7 in total_queue is produces by two status ( 8 and 4 )
amount 5 in balance_queue is produced by one status ( 4 )

note: status 4 mean queuing-----------------
status 8 mean be called

because of that in total_queue produced by all status ( 8 and 4) queuing and called.

Comment: Aren't you missing a "in" or = in your where clause? Can you elaborate the problema a Little more, because I don't finish to undestand what your question is

Comment: What exactly is `STATUS ('4')` in your `WHERE` clause?  That doesn't seem to be SQL at all.

Comment: status 4 just number of status in queue system status i used for called status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you use

```
SELECT services, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN STATUS IN ('8','4') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Total_queue, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN STATUS = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS balance_queue 
FROM tqueue 
WHERE STATUS IN ('8','4') 
    AND get_tiket BETWEEN '2016-11-10 00:00:01' AND '2016-11-10 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY services
```